# How much broadband data does Apple TV use in the menu screen?

Tags: itunes, appletv

We have a house in a rural area where broadband data is capped at a really low rate (only 9 GB per month upload and download total, then $10 per additional GB) - the only way to get broadband other than satellite is through a local provider that uses a wireless signal.

Once we have set up our Apple TV (which we have used very easily at a location with unlimited broadband), will it use data at all while we are streaming content from iTunes?

Since the Apple TV menu shows you the Netflix, YouTube and iTunes Store options, among others, I assume some data usage is inevitable.  Does anyone know how much - more importantly, how little - that data usage would be if we are just quickly checking the menu, rather than actually streaming a movie from Netflix or downloading something from iTunes?

The other option is to disconnect the wifi router from the modem when we watch Apple TV - but that's a hassle.

Comment: If you're really worried about it, you can use your home router's filtering settings to block access to the WAN from the IP assigned to your AppleTV.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a movie to be changing data 24 frames per second and compare the size of the menu art compared to the size of a movie screen you will quickly realize the menu items are negligible.

You will blow through a months worth of menu data in less than 4 minutes of a TV show through netflix or one short youtube video.

Do watch your data consumption - streaming music is moderate use - streaming video is heavy use.